# I can't find this margin-bottom code

Tags: wordpress

Here is my website : http://sourcingstrategybd.com/

I want to change (margin-bottom:100px;) in (#header-wrapper-sticky-wrapper)
but I cant find this exact location in folder => file.
Please help me, how can I change this margin.

For details please view this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIWF6.png)

Comment: That is located in your mark-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This style comes from javascript.so this css code will be removed from js file

Answer (score 0):

Its look like inline style css

so change it from that php file. or another way.

add this in your css.

```
.sticky-wrapper {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

Still not work then try this

```
#header-wrapper-sticky-wrapper {
    margin-bottom: 0!important;
}
```

Comment: Sorry to say, sir, but I already try this in main style.css page but its doesn't work.

Comment: that's why  I'm looking for this inline code and __.php file.

Comment: have you try !important; ??..!

Answer (score 0):

If you can't do this from your header php file you should be able to achieve this from your css files I believe.
Put this

```
#header-wrapper-sticky-wrapper {
    margin-bottom: 0!important;
}
```

This must work unless your'e doing any mistakes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your stylesheet:

```
#header-wrapper-sticky-wrapper.sticky-wrapper {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#header-wrapper-sticky-wrapper").css('margin-bottom','0px');

})
```

You can add this script in your footer